# webview displaying blank page even after onPageFinished function called

Tags: android, webview

In my android app, am using android native webview control to load URL contents.
It is working fine for some pages but it is not working for some other pages, instead it showing as blank page(white) even after app called onPageFinished Override method.

I am getting struggled for whole day, Could anyone please suggest me why this is behaving like this?

Comment: Show the relevant piece of code and possible errors for better help.

Comment: It does not show any error. simply show white blank page.

    `WebSettings settings = newView.getSettings();`
    `settings .setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
    `settings .setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);`
    `settings .setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);`
    `settings .setAllowFileAccess(true);`
    `settings .setDomStorageEnabled(true);`
    `settings .setSupportMultipleWindows(false);`
    `settings .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);`

Comment: Hi BramAppel, Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Some web pages require Javascript to display their contents in entirety. Verify that Javascript is enabled in you `WebView`. Post urls that are failing if this does not work for you.

Example:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Hi Jarvis, thank you for your reply. Already JavaScriptEnabled in my app. I could not figure out the reason still.

Comment: Hi Jarvis, is there any other solution?